# Windows Firewall inbound rules still blocks ports

Tags: windows-7, firewall, port, windows-firewall

I applied inbound rules for port: 1935,  as well as outbound.

When I check on canyouseeme.org, it says it (port 1935) times out.

When I completely turn off Windows 7's firewall, it works without a problem.

I can't always have that off or with my luck Freddy Kruger will slash my PC to bits.

Windows Firewall logs at `%systemroot%\system32\LogFiles\Firewall\pfirewall.log` show this:

> 2014-04-21 19:59:43 DROP TCP 107.20.89.142 10.0.0.2 52974 1935 60 S 2436636932 0 14600 - - - RECEIVE

I see the word "drop". I'm assuming that's why it's not connecting. So what's it mean and how do I fix this mess?

Comment: How about enabling the Windows Firewall log so that you can confirm the inbound traffic and see what the firewall is doing with it (allowing or denying). If you don't see it in the firewall log then you can launch a packet capture and look for it there.

Comment: Also, if this traffic is inbound then you don't need an outbound rule. Get rid of that as it only serves to complicate the troubleshooting process.

Comment: Start with the firewall log. Go to `Administrative Tools`, then to `Windows Firewall with Advanced Security`, then click the `Windows Firewall Properties` link, then for each network profile (tab) click the `Customize` button under `Logging` and enable logging for dropped packets AND successful connections. Then run your test and then open the firewall log and see what's there.

Comment: It should be at `%systemroot%\system32\LogFiles\Firewall\pfirewall.log`

Comment: Yes, the firewall log should be in the same location on a 64bit machine. By test I mean run a test from `canyouseeme.org`

Comment: `%systemroot%` is a system variable. Just type `%systemroot%` in the Run box and that will open it up. By default it will be at `C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\Firewall`.

Comment: how many ports shud i test just one or more/which

Comment: 2014-04-21 19:59:43 DROP TCP 107.20.89.142 10.0.0.2 52974 1935 60 S 2436636932 0 14600 - - - RECEIVE     i see the word drop im assuming thats why its not connecting.. so whats it mean how do i fix this mess

Comment: Yep. The firewall is dropping the incoming connection. Look at the firewall rule and make sure it allows the incoming traffic for the correct network profile (Domain, Private or Public).

Comment: what if i have all of them checked... is this not good or what

Comment: Is your rule for TCP or UDP?

Comment: 1935 is a tcp port i think...i may have applied both...

Comment: i applied the rule joe long ago no difference

Comment: possible duplicate of [firewall blocks connection even though allowed](http://superuser.com/questions/836574/firewall-blocks-connection-even-though-allowed)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve but I would try Comodo firewall as it lets you be selective of what you allow to happen on your system. Remember if you do this to not have both windows firewall and comodo running at the same time.

Comment: thanks for the back up plan, but i really cant add outside firewalls

Comment: Not even if you tried it on a usb stick or something like that?